# pytest: How to output green checkmark instead of PASSED in short test summary

Tags: pytest

I'm testing a linux distribution using pytest. The output should be clean and simple.

My prototype looks like this:

[image: python prototype]

The actual output of my python script using pytest looks like this:

[image: pytest output]

The ..F is OK.
The "short test summary info" line is not needed.
Most importantly i want to have a green ✔ instead of PASSED!

I have found the [pytest-custom-report](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-custom-report/) plugin, but it can't change the short test summary.

Comment: you'll need to write a custom reporter plugin, nothing out of the box exists as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a [change](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4667) in PyTest, included in 4.2.0, the plugin [pytest-custom-report](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-custom-report/issues/2#issuecomment-459131237) is also able to modify the short test summary.